# Sequences and series problem Algebra

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have a line of whole numbers from 1 to 128. We delete the first number and leave the second one then erase the third one and leave the fourth one... Example: 2, 4, 6 ... When we are done with the first iteration we repeat the process from the last number left. We delete the last number and leave the penultimate number ... Then we repeat the process again until one number is left. What is the last number?
I am sorry but I cannot provide an attempted solution beacuse I do not know how to approach the problem.
Answer:86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time round: you got rid of the numbers which are $1$ mod $2$ (so the first and last numbers are now $2$ and $128$), then the numbers which are $0$ mod $4$ (so the first and last numbers are now $2$ and $126$). So you're left with the numbers which are $2$ mod $4$.

The next time round, you got rid of the numbers which are $2$ mod $8$ (so the first and last numbers are $6$ and $126$), leaving the numbers $6$ mod $8$, then the numbers which are $14$ mod $16$ (so the first and last numbers are now $6$ and $118$), leaving the numbers $6$ mod $16$.

Just keep going like that: at each stage, you're killing the numbers which are something mod the next power of $2$, and you just need to keep track of the first and last numbers in the range to work out what you're getting rid of.